How should I configure electron-builder.yml to include arbitrary file in build output?
I am writing electron app which has to use standalone database (sqlite3 but it could be anything else). Database structure (metadata, SQL script or whatever else) is in a text file that I want included in the build directory as-is. The script is in directory sql (subdirectory in the project tree, same level as src, node_modules etc.).
I looked into electron-builder.yml and some documentation and thought I would solve my problem by adding a line specifying the directory containing my scripts.
Original content:
files:
  - '!**/.vscode/*'
  - '!src/*'
  - '!electron.vite.config.{js,ts,mjs,cjs}'
  - '!{.eslintignore,.eslintrc.cjs,.prettierignore,.prettierrc.yaml,dev-app-update.yml,CHANGELOG.md,README.md}'
  - '!{.env,.env.*,.npmrc,pnpm-lock.yaml}'
  - '!{tsconfig.json,tsconfig.node.json,tsconfig.web.json}'

after modification:
files:
  - '!**/.vscode/*'
  - '!src/*'
  - '!electron.vite.config.{js,ts,mjs,cjs}'
  - '!{.eslintignore,.eslintrc.cjs,.prettierignore,.prettierrc.yaml,dev-app-update.yml,CHANGELOG.md,README.md}'
  - '!{.env,.env.*,.npmrc,pnpm-lock.yaml}'
  - '!{tsconfig.json,tsconfig.node.json,tsconfig.web.json}'
  - 'sql'

I also tried moving sql/ directory into src/ and change electron-builder.yml but after npm run dev the directory is not copied to out/, nor to /build, which is what I would like to achieve.
Used dev packages:
electron, electron-builder, electron-vite, vite and a few more, but I believe these are essential for the problem.

This question is similar to: How to add folders and files to electron build using electron-builder. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
